# t value for simple regression analysis

Tags: regression, logistic

I have the following data.[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsRLm.png)

Then I got a t-value by running excel. [t-stat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMA4s.png)

The thing is, I wanted to know how I could get this value without using excel, and just by finding a suitable equation by myself. What I found is this. [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyr5y.png), where x-bar is the sample mean, u is the population mean, n is the sample size and s is the standard deviation of the sample. I found each of them and substituted them into the equation, but what I got was different from the excel. Is this because I Made a mistake in my calculation? I'm new to statistics, so maybe I'm asking a weird question.

I want to know the equation used in Excel, for getting the t-value of the gradient and the intercept of the simple regression analysis.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) says:

> The *t*-test is **any** statistical hypothesis test in which the test statistic follows a Student's t-distribution under the null hypothesis. (Emphasis added.)

The equation you link to:

$$t=\frac{\bar x - \mu}{s/\sqrt{n}} $$

is only for the case of a one-sample t-test when you are comparing the mean of a set of observations $\bar x$ against a specified value $\mu$.

Your Excel model is a linear regression of price against area, so that formula isn't what you need. The *t* statistic that you highlighted in the Excel report is for the *slope of the regression line*. Several ways to do the calculations for that application of a *t*-test are provided [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Slope_of_a_regression_line).